# coroutine flow doesn't emit before exception

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

i have flow in my repository that first emits local data, then loading data from api

```
override fun getAllTasks(): Flow<List<TodoItemDto>> = flow{
        Log.d("debugg", "get local tasks")
        val version = taskLocalDatasource.getCacheVersion()
        val localTasks = taskLocalDatasource.getAllTasks()
        emit(localTasks)
        //delay(100) if i put delay here, everything works as expected
        Log.d("debugg", "get api tasks")
        val apiTasks = taskApiDatasource.getAllTasks(version)
        emit(apiTasks.second)
        taskLocalDatasource.cacheTasks(
            apiTasks.first,
            apiTasks.second
        )

    }
```

but if there is an exception in api, even the first emit not working

my flow usecase implementation

```
abstract class SimpleFlowUseCase<out R>{

abstract fun execute(): Flow<R>

operator fun invoke(): Flow<Result<R>> {
    return execute()
        .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
        .onEach { Log.d("debugg", "invoke() called ${it.size}") }
        .map {
            Result.success(it)
        }
        .catch {
            Log.e("error", "usecase ${this::class.simpleName} fails", it)
            emit(Result.failure(it))
        }
}
```

}

**the expected result with exception in api:**
get local tasks
invoke() called 2
get api tasks
usecase {name} fails

**actual result:**
get local tasks
get api tasks

Comment: How does "execute" interact with "getAllTasks"?